# Decoding a Json with multiple possible types per key

Tags: json, swift

im trying to decode a Json that has this structure

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "list": {
                "name": "Landesliste Rheinland-Pfalz",
                "won": true
              },
            "constituency": {
              "id": "ABDWE-DWDWID",
              "won": true
            },
        },
        {
            "list": {
                "name": "Landesliste Rheinland-Pfalz",
                "won": true
              },
            "constituency": [],
        },
    ]
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the value for key `"constituency"`is sometimes and empty Array and sometimes contains two other keys.
How can I decode this? I've tries with making `var constituency: Constituency?` optional. But that didn't work

```
struct JsonCoder: Codable {
    var items: [Item]
    struct Item: Codable {
        var list: List?
        var Constituency: Constituency?
        struct list: Codable {
            var name: String
            var won: Bool
        }
        struct Constituency: Codable {
            var id: String
            var won: Bool
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need it to be an object or `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums with associated values come to the rescue, and if you're certain that if `constituency` is an array, it is always empty, you can get away with something like this:

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let list: List
    let constituency: ConstituencyUnion
}

enum ConstituencyUnion: Codable {
    case constituencyClass(ConstituencyClass)
    case dummyArray([Int])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([Int].self) {
            self = .dummyArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(ConstituencyClass.self) {
            self = .constituencyClass(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(ConstituencyUnion.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for ConstituencyUnion"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .constituencyClass(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .dummyArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

struct ConstituencyClass: Codable {
    let id: String
    let won: Bool
}

struct List: Codable {
    let name: String
    let won: Bool
}
```

You can then access the data using pattern matching in a `switch`:

```
do {
  let res = JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
  switch res.items[0].constituency {
  case .constituencyClass(let constituency):
    print(constituency.id)
  default:
    print("no constituency")
  }
} catch { ... }
```

Comment: How would I then access it? if I access `.constituency` I cannot access the values

Comment: Use `switch` - I'll update the answer with a sample

Answer (score 0):

Use custom decoder. For example if you need that value to be either a `Constituency` object or `nil`, use this custom decoder:

```
struct JsonCoder: Codable {
    var items: [Item]

    struct Item: Codable {
        var list: List?
        var constituency: Constituency?

        struct list: Codable {
            var name: String
            var won: Bool
        }

        struct Constituency: Codable {
            var id: String
            var won: Bool
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.constituency = try? container.decode(Constituency.self, forKey: .constituency) // This will return `nil` if it fails to decode it as `Constituency`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I didn't try it because I decode differently.